# Trying to launch a python script with systemd but it doesnt work on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-3.x, linux, systemd

It runs normally in Mu, but when i try to run it with systemd (to run when RPI is turned on) it doesn't work.

here's the error from the terminal

```
● skateboard.service - skateboard
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/skateboard.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-03-30 21:38:19 EDT; 14s ago
  Process: 467 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/PythonScripts/skateboard.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 467 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]: serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]:   File "/home/pi/Desktop/PythonScripts/skateboard.py", line 11, in <module>
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]:     lineString = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 509, in read
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]:     raise SerialException('read failed: {}'.format(e))
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi python3[467]: serial.serialutil.SerialException: read failed: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: skateboard.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 30 21:38:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: skateboard.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Also if its relevant, here's the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import serial

port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
ser = serial.Serial(port, 57600)
shock = 0

while 1:
    while ser.in_waiting:

        lineString = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()



        lineInt = float(lineString)
        print(lineInt)

        if(lineInt >= .4):
            shock = 1

        if(shock == 1 and lineInt < 5):

            ser.write(b"Shock!\n")
            print("shock")
            shock = 0
```

And here's the .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=skateboard
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/skateboard.py
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hello Alex, have you disabled kernel debugging over that serial port? You can also try to make your code more resilient to glitches on the port connection handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment above I think the problem might be that the serial console is not disabled and the messages it's spitting are interfering with your program. So the first thing to do is to make sure the console is disabled. The complete procedure is explained [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) but it's quite simple: just run `sudo raspi-config` and select *Interface Options* on the menu and then *Serial Port*. Answer `No` to the first question to disable the console and then `Yes` to enable the port for your purposes, reboot, and you are done.

Next thing you should do is make sure the user running the service (`pi`) is a member of the `dialup` group to be able to access the serial port. To do that just run:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi
```

on the command line.

Depending on how reliable is your serial link (and that depends on a whole lot of things, like wiring distance, quality, and the like) you might need to make your code more reliable to catch exceptions (maybe you are lucky and the port works just fine for a while but at some point, your device might fail to send data and your service will crash so adding exception handling is more than good practice in this case) Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import serial

port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
ser = serial.Serial(port, 57600)
shock = 0

while 1:
    while ser.in_waiting:
        #Handle exception, i.e. serial port not reading anything
        try: 
            lineString = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            lineInt = float(lineString)
            print(lineInt)

            if(lineInt >= .4):
                shock = 1

            if(shock == 1 and lineInt < 5):

                ser.write(b"Shock!\n")
                print("shock")
                shock = 0

        except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
            print("Something went wrong, no data received!")
```

Comment: I did the things you suggested, and they didn't seem to work, but i tried changing up the script, by running with and without ```try: except serial.serialutil.SerialException:```, and it shows the same error when that part isn't in the code, so do you think that the problem is with the python script or something else? I can show the error if you'd like, also some relevant info that might be good to know is that the RPI is connected to an arduino which is connected to a GPS module, and a relay. So when the RPI sends a command, the arduino will trigger the relay.

Comment: after adding the `try/except` it still shows the same `serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data` error? I don't think it matters that there is an Arduino in between

Comment: um yeah so im just using an arduino inbetween to hold all the relay and gps data, and the RPI to read and do the commands, i guess i could do it all in the arduino, but i want to learn RPI